# Magazine publishing software with RTL support

Tags: software-rec, right-to-left

We want to publish an electronic magazine about to free software applications such as Gimp, Inkscape, GNU/Linux and so on. We need a magazine or book design application similar to InDesign of the Windows world. We found Scribus, but our language is written right-to-left and Scribus doesn't support RTL. What can we use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 2021, CTL (Complex Text Layout including RTL) support added to Scribus developement branche 1.5.3 (will be included in 1.6 stable version).